# iOS and Protools

Tags: ios, avfoundation, synchronization, mpmediaplayercontroller, timecodes

Can I sync a movie played in ProTools and iOS using time codes? Has anybody ever done this? I have just gotten started with this project and I need to play a movie simultaneously in the iPad and the protools console, with the time seek function only in the console.

Comment: I've just been searching around for some possible techniques that I can implement this but couldn't get any lead. I might be wrong, but this doesn't look like it's been implemented before - atleast in an open-source sort of way!

Comment: I have no experience with this, but I would look into mapping time in iOS to SMPTE or possibly MIDI/OSC. Maybe use protools as the SMPTE master, and iOS as a slave. Good luck.